# How can the velocity of electrons in graphene be measured?

Tags: electrons, velocity, speed, graphene

I'm trying to understand how one can measure the velocity of electrons in graphene, from an experimental point of view.
Does anyone have some clue?

Comment: why dont you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity#Experimental_measure